# I check API endpoints using POSTMAN. But its post HTTP method is not working properly

Tags: javascript, backend, koa

I check API endpoints using POSTMAN. But its post HTTP method is not working properly. This is the user login backend code. Get data from the mongo DB database and validated the user login. After validating user can easily log in to the system.

```
userRouter.post("/user/login", async ctx => {
    const data = ctx.request.body;
    const student =  loginUser(data);
    ctx.body = {status: student};
    ctx.status = 201;
    ctx.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be setting the response to the request...

try this:

```
userRouter.post("/user/add", async (ctx, res) => {
    const data = ctx.request.body;
    const student =  registerStudent(data);
    

    res.json({success:true});
    
});

userRouter.post("/user/login", async (ctx, res) => {
    const data = ctx.request.body;
    const student =  loginUser(data);

    res.json({status:student};

});
```

Answer (score -1):

In the user router file, please use the ' await ' keyword before these methods.

```
registerStudent(data);
loginUser(data);
```

In the example, you can use

```
userRouter.post("/user/add", async ctx => {
    const data = ctx.request.body;
    const student = await registerStudent(data);
    ctx.body = {success:true};
    ctx.status = 201;
    ctx.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});
```